# How do I bind an ObservableConcurrentDictionary to WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I am trying to bind the Microsoft sample `ObservableConcurrentDictionary.cs` object to a `TreeView`. I have searched for examples on binding a Dictionary but although there are many examples, none of them seem to work for me. Whenever I run it the screen shows up with an empty `treeview` (only white outline). I have stripped down my code to the bare minimum to test and my implementation is as follows:

```
<Window x:Name="AppWindow" x:Class="ControlCenter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Control Center" Height="1000" Width="1200"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid x:Name="left_grid" Margin="362,199,551,237">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding _hostList}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding _hostList.Values}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _hostList = new ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _hostList.Add("TestHost1", "Host1");
        _hostList.Add("TestHost2", "Host2");
        _hostList.Add("TestHost3", "Host3");
    } 
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace System.Collections.Concurrent
{
[DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
public class ObservableConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes an instance of the ObservableConcurrentDictionary class.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableConcurrentDictionary()
    {
        _context = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
        _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    /// <summary>Event raised when the collection changes.</summary>
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    /// <summary>Event raised when a property on the collection changes.</summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies observers of CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged of an update to the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    private void NotifyObserversOfChange()
    {
        var collectionHandler = CollectionChanged;
        var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (collectionHandler != null || propertyHandler != null)
        {
            _context.Post(s =>
            {
                if (collectionHandler != null)
                {
                    collectionHandler(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                }
                if (propertyHandler != null)
                {
                    propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                    propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                    propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to be added.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
    private bool TryAddWithNotification(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return TryAddWithNotification(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be added.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the item to be added.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
    private bool TryAddWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        bool result = _dictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
        if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange();
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>Attempts to remove an item from the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be removed.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the item removed.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the removal was successful.</returns>
    private bool TryRemoveWithNotification(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        bool result = _dictionary.TryRemove(key, out value);
        if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange();
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>Attempts to add or update an item in the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be updated.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The new value to set for the item.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the update was successful.</returns>
    private void UpdateWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _dictionary[key] = value;
        NotifyObserversOfChange();
    }

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        TryAddWithNotification(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Clear();
        NotifyObserversOfChange();
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Contains(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    int ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Count
    {
        get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Count; }
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        TValue temp;
        return TryRemoveWithNotification(item.Key, out temp);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        TryAddWithNotification(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return _dictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        TValue temp;
        return TryRemoveWithNotification(key, out temp);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return _dictionary.Values; }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[key]; }
        set { UpdateWithNotification(key, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems. First since you didn't specify a source in your binding it is going off of the `DataContext` which is `null`.

I think you are thinking that since you are working with `MainWindow` that the source of your binding statements will be the `MainWindow` object but that isn't the default for a binding. If you wanted to do that you would have to use a `RelativeSource` in your bindings, but usually you would just pop the collection into the `DataContext` as part of a view model or directly as the entire view model instead. Something like this:

```
public ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _hostList = new ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _hostList.Add("TestHost1", "Host1");
    _hostList.Add("TestHost2", "Host2");
    _hostList.Add("TestHost3", "Host3");
    DataContext = _hostList;
}
```

Then you will just have your bindings go off of the `DataContext` so you would update your code as follows:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Values}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This won't completely resolve your problems I am thinking though since I think you are binding to the wrong properties. ItemsSource should be binding to something that is an `IEnumerable` of some sort and `Text` should be binding to a `string`.

So I am not sure what you are ideally trying to show but am pretty sure you aren't binding correctly. Usually with a `TreeView` you will be using a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step/) and I think this is likely what you are wanting to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you need to bind to a property, not a type (string). or the bindings won't work. Specifically

```
 public ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, string>...
```

should be

```
 public ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, myobj>...
```

and be sure the data shown is a proper property, not a field. ie.

```
       public class myobj {
            public string mystg { get; set; }
        }
```

with setting

```
  listBox.ItemsSource = _hostList;
```

(well you did a tree, I tested with a list view)
Then binding should be

```
{Binding Value.mystg}
```

I do note, that the dictionary doesn't support sorting, and new items added appeared random in my view, so sorting might be another animal.